# What is The difference Between ColumnCount and Columns.Count in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridviewcolumn

I am using datagridview for a lot of things and I think it's a really strong data viewer tool. My Problem is, I am using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.**Columns.Count** - 1; i++)
{
  ....                
}
```

My question is, what is the difference between `dataGridView1.Columns.Count` and `dataGridView1.ColumnCount`.

They both return an integer that holds the number of columns in the `dataGridView1` I searched only but couldn't find anything. I hope you guy help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we consult *reference source*

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,84e79a2ba1ae9635,references

we'll see *no difference* with respect of `get` accessor:

```
    public int ColumnCount
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Columns.Count;
        }
        set
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

It seems `DataGridView.ColumnCount` property has been designed in order to provide `set` in which we can add / remove columns

Comment: Thank you, I just learned that we can set columncount. I always add and remove to control the number of columns. Thank you mate